# Добавить telegram bot в django проект

Tags: django, telegram

хотел бы попросить советов по логике построения моего приложения. Ввиду отсутствия опыта зашёл в некоторый тупик. Кейс: парсер некоего сайта, например с вакансиями или объявлениями, собранная  инфа складывается в бд и выдаётся пользователю посредством telegram бота выбранными порциями. Организовано как django проект, парсер как app внутри него, будет запускаться посредством manage по шедулеру, так же будет небольшой web front.
Основной вопрос в том, как грамотно прикрутить в этот проект бота? Он должен быть как просто ещё один app в django проекте? Если да, то он должен быть просто как контроллер?

Comment: я ботов выношу в отдельное приложение, пишу класс для работы с ботом и вызываю что нужно где хочу. обычно через management command запускаю бота, который работает пока  ему не надоест

Comment: Лучше прикрутить работу с ботом как отдельное приложение. И можно использовать https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot библиотеку для работы с телеграм API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно прикручиваю отдельным django app. Есть хороший [темплейт](https://github.com/ohld/django-telegram-bot) как раз для связки django + telegram. Попробуй посмотреть, как там это организовано.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]